# show that $x^4+y^4+z^4=1$ is compact and has no boundary

Tags: general-topology

I'm trying to show $x^4+y^4+z^4=1$ is closed surface. so i finally reached to this definition: a closed surface is compact and has no boundary. despite i had learned several elementary topological definitions such as open, closed set, limit point...etc, it's still hard work for me.

how can i show such 3D surface is compact, and has no boundary? please help me in detail....

Comment: @MrTanorus: If you go to edit your question, you'll see that the way to MathJax your formulas is (to first order) to enclose them in dollar signs.  There are some markups which you can learn at the links provided above...

Comment: @CameronWilliams Will they not have to show there are no singular points, as well?

Comment: You know it is closed because it's a preimage of {1} under a continuous map.  Then use your theorem.

Comment: oh, dollar sign. thanks. and thanks for answers

Comment: @CameronWilliams I feel the definition of "boundary" is the manifold-one, not the topological, and they disagree. For instance, the topological boundary of a sphere in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is the sphere itself, whereas the manifold-boundary is empty.

Comment: @AloizioMacedo Oh shoot you're right. I didn't even think about that.